# Приглашение ко входу у пользователя Ubuntu выглядит как $

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, debian, .bashrc

Почему приглашение ко входу у одного из пользователей Ubuntu которого я создал командой `useradd -m USER` выглядит как `$` и больше нету ничего, ни имени пользователя, ни хоста? Также не работает автодополнение и история.

Я пытался редактировать файлы `.profile` и `.bashrc` в каталоге этого пользователя, но ничего не происходит.

Если я создаю пользователя командой не `useradd`, а `adduser`, то всё работает корректно.

Я также добавлял в этот каталог конфиги других пользователей, у которых всё нормально, но опять ничего не происходит.

В чём может быть проблема? Как её решить?

Comment: Существует ли домашняя директория у пользователя, выставлены ли корректно права на нее?

Comment: Да, существует домашняя директория и владелец её именно тот пользователь для кого она создана

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У пользователя в качестве шелла задан `sh` вместо `bash`. Фикс:

От рута:

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/bash [имя пользователя который поломался]
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Это работает для меня)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $SHELL
```

посмотреть какой шелл установлен для текущего пользователя

```
echo $0
```

посмотреть какой именно шелл запущен в данном терминале
*(один шел может быть вложен в другой)*

```
chsh -l
```

посмотреть какие оболочки шелл доступны

```
chsh -s <shell> <username>
```

установить шелл (из списка `chsh -l`) для указанного пользователя

Comment: Этот способ так же отлично работает